# Fullscreen button not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a custom video player, and obviously I want a full screen button. When I click it, it goes to full screen, but doesn't fill up the entire screen. By the way, I'm just trying to use javascript, css3 and html5. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Also the way everything is setup is:

divider: video, range, div, enddiv, endiv

I want the first divider to go fullscreen along with everything inside it.
Please check my code below:

```js
var vid, playbtn, seekslider, mutebtn, volumeslider, oldvol, fullscreenbtn, vidplr, cross, warning, isFullscreen;

function initializePlayer(){
  //Set object references
  vid = document.getElementById("video");
  playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
  seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
  mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
  volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider");
  fullscreenbtn = document.getElementById("fullscreenbtn");
  vidplr = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
  cross = document.getElementById("cross");
  warning = document.getElementById("warning");
  isFullscreen = false;
  //Add event listeners
  playbtn.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
  seekslider.addEventListener("change", vidSeek, false);
  vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", seektimeupdate, false);
  mutebtn.addEventListener("click", vidmute, false);
  volumeslider.addEventListener("change", setvolume, false);
  fullscreenbtn.addEventListener("click", toggleFullScreen, false);
  cross.addEventListener("click", removewarning, false);
  vid.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);

  //IfChrome
  var isChromium = window.chrome,
      winNav = window.navigator,
      vendorName = winNav.vendor,
      isOpera = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("OPR") > -1,
      isIEedge = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1,
      isIOSChrome = winNav.userAgent.match("CriOS");

  if(isIOSChrome){
    // is Google Chrome on IOS
    warning.parentNode.removeChild(warning);  
  } else if(isChromium !== null && isChromium !== undefined && vendorName === "Google Inc." && isOpera == false && isIEedge == false) {
    // is Google Chrome
    warning.parentNode.removeChild(warning);  
  } else { 
    // not Google Chrome 
    //ERROR! DISPLAY WARNING
  }
}
window.onload = initializePlayer;

function removewarning() {
  warning.parentNode.removeChild(warning);  
}
function playPause() {
  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    playbtn.style.background = "url(pause.png)";
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    playbtn.style.background = "url(play.png)";
  }
}
function vidSeek(){
  var seekto = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 700);
  vid.currentTime = seekto;
}
function seektimeupdate(){
  var nt = vid.currentTime * (700 / vid.duration);
  seekslider.value = nt;
}
function vidmute() {
  if(vid.muted){
    volumeslider.value = oldvol;
    vid.muted = false;
    mutebtn.style.background = "url(unmuted.png)";
  } else {
    oldvol = volumeslider.value;
    volumeslider.value = 0;
    vid.muted = true;
    mutebtn.style.background = "url(muted.png)";
  }
}
function setvolume(){
  vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
}
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
      !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
    if (vidplr.requestFullscreen) {
      vidplr.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (vidplr.msRequestFullscreen) {
      vidplr.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (vidplr.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      vidplr.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (vidplr.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      vidplr.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display: none;
}
div#videocontroller {
  background: #dedbc4;
}
body {
  background:#e4e4e4;
}
div#videoplayer {
  width:640px;
  height:401px;
}
input#seekslider {
  width:640px;
  background: #93C97E;
  height:4px;
}
input#seekslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background:url(seekersliderhandle.png);
  height:19px;
  width:19px;
  border-radius:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:0px solid #000000;
}
button#playpausebtn{
  background:url(pause.png);
  border:none;
  width:33px;
  height:25px;
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity:0.5;
}
button#playpausebtn:hover{ opacity:1; }
input#volumeslider{ width: 80px;}
input[type='range'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background: #000;
  border:#666 1px solid;
  height:4px;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background: #FFF;
  height:15px;
  width:15px;
  border-radius:100%;
  cursor:pointer;
}
input#volumeslider{
  top: 50%;
}
button#mutebtn{
  background:url(unmuted.png);
  border:none;
  width:20px;
  height:25px;
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity:0.5;
}
button#fullscreenbtn{
  background:url(isfullscreen.png);
  border:none;
  width:29px;
  height:25px;
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity:0.5;
}
div#warning{
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#7F0000;
  background:#FFADAD;
  padding:0px;
}
p#chromewarningtext{
  color:#FF0000;
  font-family: "Arial", "Verdana"; 
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}
button#cross{
  font-family: "Arial", "Verdana";
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top:20px;
  background:#FFADAD;
  border:none;
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity:0.5;
}
video{
  width:640px;
  height:360px;
}
div#videoplayer.fullscreen{
  z-index: 9999; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
}
video.fullscreen{
  z-index: 9999;
  width: screen.width;
  height: screen.height-41px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="warning">
  <p id="chromewarningtext">This site works best on Google Chrome. Broken features won't be fixed on other browsers.<a id="chromelink" href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/">Download Google Chrome now.</a></p><button id="cross">x</button>
</div>
<div id="videoplayer">
  <video id="video" preload autoplay>
    <source src="../theuploads.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
  </video>
  <div id="controlbar">
    <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="700" value="0" step="1">
    <div id="videocontroller">
      <button id="playpausebtn"></button>
      <button id="mutebtn"></button>
      <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
      <button id="fullscreenbtn"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not add all of your code here, but the better way is try to add your codes in different parts and with headline and divided

Answer (score 0):

You have a `video.fullscreen` in your CSS, but nowhere do you assign that class in your JS. You will to do some sort of class.add / class.remove in the fullscreen-function.

Here's a working example of proper catching of the ESC-button, and so on.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      video::-webkit-media-controls {
        display: none;
      }
      div#videocontroller {
        background: #dedbc4;
      }
      body {
        background:#e4e4e4;
      }
      div#videoplayer {
        width:640px;
        height:401px;
      }
      input#seekslider {
        width:640px;
        background: #93C97E;
        height:4px;
      }
      input#seekslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none !important;
        background:url(seekersliderhandle.png);
        height:19px;
        width:19px;
        border-radius:3px;
        cursor:pointer;
        border:0px solid #000000;
      }
      button#playpausebtn{
        background:url(pause.png);
        border:none;
        width:33px;
        height:25px;
        cursor:pointer;
        opacity:0.5;
      }
      button#playpausebtn:hover{ opacity:1; }
      input#volumeslider{ width: 80px;}
      input[type='range'] {
        -webkit-appearance: none !important;
        background: #000;
        border:#666 1px solid;
        height:4px;
      }
      input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none !important;
        background: #FFF;
        height:15px;
        width:15px;
        border-radius:100%;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
      input#volumeslider{
        top: 50%;
      }
      button#mutebtn{
        background:url(unmuted.png);
        border:none;
        width:20px;
        height:25px;
        cursor:pointer;
        opacity:0.5;
      }
      button#fullscreenbtn{
        background:url(isfullscreen.png);
        border:none;
        width:29px;
        height:25px;
        cursor:pointer;
        opacity:0.5;
      }
      div#warning{
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#7F0000;
        background:#FFADAD;
        padding:0px;
      }
      p#chromewarningtext{
        color:#FF0000;
        font-family: "Arial", "Verdana"; 
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      button#cross{
        font-family: "Arial", "Verdana";
        font-size: 16px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top:20px;
        background:#FFADAD;
        border:none;
        cursor:pointer;
        opacity:0.5;
      }
      video{
        width:640px;
        height:360px;
      }
      div#videoplayer.fullscreen{
        z-index: 9999; 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%; 
        position: fixed; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 
      }
      video.fullscreen{
        z-index: 9999;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
      }

    </style>
 </head>
  <script>
    var vid, playbtn, seekslider, mutebtn, volumeslider, oldvol, fullscreenbtn, vidplr, cross, warning, isFullscreen;

    function initializePlayer(){
      //Set object references
      vid = document.getElementById("video");
      playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
      seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
      mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
      volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider");
      fullscreenbtn = document.getElementById("fullscreenbtn");
      vidplr = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
      cross = document.getElementById("cross");
      warning = document.getElementById("warning");
      isFullscreen = false;
      //Add event listeners
      playbtn.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
      seekslider.addEventListener("change", vidSeek, false);
      vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", seektimeupdate, false);
      mutebtn.addEventListener("click", vidmute, false);
      volumeslider.addEventListener("change", setvolume, false);
      fullscreenbtn.addEventListener("click", toggleFullScreen, false);
      cross.addEventListener("click", removewarning, false);
      vid.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
      document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", exitHandler, false);
      document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", exitHandler, false);
      document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", exitHandler, false);

      //IfChrome
      var isChromium = window.chrome,
        winNav = window.navigator,
        vendorName = winNav.vendor,
        isOpera = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("OPR") > -1,
        isIEedge = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1,
        isIOSChrome = winNav.userAgent.match("CriOS");

      if(isIOSChrome){
        // is Google Chrome on IOS
        warning.parentNode.removeChild(warning);  
      } else if(isChromium !== null && isChromium !== undefined && vendorName === "Google Inc." && isOpera == false && isIEedge == false) {
         // is Google Chrome
         warning.parentNode.removeChild(warning);  
      } else { 
         // not Google Chrome 
         //ERROR! DISPLAY WARNING
      }
    }
    window.onload = initializePlayer;

    function removewarning() {
      warning.parentNode.removeChild(warning);  
    }
    function playPause() {
      if (vid.paused) {
        vid.play();
        playbtn.style.background = "url(pause.png)";
      } else {
        vid.pause();
        playbtn.style.background = "url(play.png)";
      }
    }
    function vidSeek(){
      var seekto = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 700);
      vid.currentTime = seekto;
    }
    function seektimeupdate(){
      var nt = vid.currentTime * (700 / vid.duration);
      seekslider.value = nt;
    }
    function vidmute() {
        if(vid.muted){
            volumeslider.value = oldvol;
            vid.muted = false;
            mutebtn.style.background = "url(unmuted.png)";
        } else {
            oldvol = volumeslider.value;
            volumeslider.value = 0;
            vid.muted = true;
            mutebtn.style.background = "url(muted.png)";
        }
    }
    function setvolume(){
      vid.volume = volumeslider.value / 100;
    }


function exitHandler() {
    var fullscreenElement = document.fullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement;
    if (fullscreenElement == null) {
      vid.classList.remove('fullscreen');
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
      }
    }
}

    function toggleFullScreen(e) {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
    !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
    vid.classList.add('fullscreen');
    if (vidplr.requestFullscreen) {
      vidplr.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (vidplr.msRequestFullscreen) {
      vidplr.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (vidplr.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      vidplr.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (vidplr.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      vidplr.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  }
}
  </script>
  <body>
    <div id="warning">
      <p id="chromewarningtext">This site works best on Google Chrome. Broken features won't be fixed on other browsers.<a id="chromelink" href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/">Download Google Chrome now.</a></p><button id="cross">x</button>
    </div>
    <div id="videoplayer">
      <video id="video" preload autoplay>
        <source src="testvid.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
      </video>
      <div id="controlbar">
        <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="700" value="0" step="1">
        <div id="videocontroller">
          <button id="playpausebtn"></button>
          <button id="mutebtn"></button>
          <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
          <button id="fullscreenbtn" title="fullscreen"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It breaks the player.

Comment: How? Are you talking about the missing controls? That's because you haven't added logic for viewing them in full-screen.

Comment: The updated code in my answer catches the ESC-keypress, and works in both Firefox and Chrome, it seems. Since I don't have the images for the player-buttons, the interface is a bit broken, but you'll have to do a little bit yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `100vh` for `height` and `100vw` for width instead of the `100%`

Comment: where do I replace them??

Comment: In the rule for the fullscreen videoplayer div